# How can I subtract a fixed date from a columns of date in excel file using Python?

Tags: python, date, csv

I have a file with the below format:

```
name           date
sam          21/1/2003
bil          5/4/2006
sam          4/7/2009
Mali         24/7/2009
bil          13/2/2008
etc...
```

I want to set a fix date for instance: 1/1/2003 and subtract all of the dates from my fix date  and divide them by week to find out which names are registered in which weeks and put them in a set. So I would like to get the below final result:

```
Sam=[week3,week12]
bil=[week25,week13] etc..
```

I have write the below python script but It is not working.I have this error:

```
 val=set(start_date-'date(data.files.datetime)')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Anyone has any idea what is the best way to write the code for it?

```
import pprint
import csv


with open('d:/Results/names_info.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    start_date= 1/1/2003
    filereader=csv.reader(csvfile,'excel')
    for row in filereader:
         for name in row:
             key=name
             val=set(start_date-'date(data.files.datetime)')
             datedict[key]=val


pprint.pprint (datedict)
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: I put the error type in the above description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

1. Not ignoring the first line of your csv file which contains 'name' and 'date'.
2. Using strings to store dates instead of the `date` type.
3. Attempting to subtract one string from another.
4. Modifying items in `datedict` without first checking that they exist.
5. The slashes in 1/1/2003 are going to be treated as divide signs and the result will be 0.

Here is what your code would look like with these errors fixed:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime
from datetime import date
import math

def weeks(filename, start_date):
    # The defaultdict class will create items when a key is accessed that does
    # not exist
    datedict = defaultdict(set)
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, 'excel')
        read_header = False
        for row in filereader:
            # Ignore the first row of the file
            if not read_header:
                read_header = True
                continue

            # Strip out any whitespace
            cells = [col.strip() for col in row]
            name = cells[0]
            date_str = cells[1]

            # Parse the date string into a date
            row_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y').date()

            # Calculate the difference between dates
            delta = start_date-row_date
            # Convert from days to weeks, you could use math.floor() here if
            # needed
            delta_weeks = int(math.ceil(delta.days / 7.0))

            datedict[name].add(delta_weeks)

    return datedict

date_dict = weeks('a.csv', start_date=date(year=2013, month=1, day=1))
for name, dates in date_dict.iteritems():
    print name, list(dates)
```

This prints out:

```
bil [351, 254]
sam [519, 182]
Mali [179]
```

You should be able to figure out how to get it to print 'weeks'.

Comment: You must have extra columns in the file, or it is not being read correctly by csv. Try printing out the contents of `row`.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to make use of the `datetime` module in the standard library.  A quick and dirty method to calculate the week difference could be the following:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2003,1,1)  # (YYYY,MM,DD)
another_date = datetime.date(2003,10,20)

difference = start_date - another_date  # another datetime object
weeks_between = difference.days / 7 + 1 # integer division, first week = 1
```

also if you want a `dict` of `list`s replace `datedict[key]=val` with

```
try :
    datedict[key] += [val]  # add the element val to your existing list
except KeyError :           # catch error if key not in dict yet
    datedict[key] = [val]   # add key to dict with val as one element list
```

also if you'd prefer the lists to have strings of the form week1, week12 etc then simply use

```
val = 'week%d' % val
```